# How to pass an object to a web service in .web project from silverlight project?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I have a user defined class (e.g., Measure) in silverlight project, and I want to pass its object (e.g., measureObject) to a web service for further processing. But it seems that .web project doesn't recognize Measure class at all.

How can I work around it? Should I use serialization to fulfill this, Any examples? What's the procedures for this serialization (1. define the class serializable [System.Serializable] or [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Measure")] ?, 2. serialize the object before pass it to the service, 3. pass to the service and deserialize it for processing)?

Many thanks,

Wei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your Measure class in your service with attributes. Then you can create a service method that accepts the Measure class as a parameter.

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName;

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName;
}
```

Then, when you update the service reference in your Silverlight project you will use the class declared in the service with its appropriate function.

Comment: Thanks for youranswer, Shiznit123. That's really helpful.